# SPlist to SQL table using client object model

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am trying to push a SharePoint List `emp` to a SQL Table

Here is my code. What I am doing wrong?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sp2010/");
        Web web = context.Web;
        List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Emp");
        context.Load(list);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(list.Title + "\n");
        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml = "<View/>";
        ListItemCollection allitems = list.GetItems(query);
        context.Load(allitems);
        context.ExecuteQuery();



        foreach (ListItem listitem in allitems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listitem["desc"].ToString());

            string connString = "connection string";
            string a = "insert into emp";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(a, conn);
            conn.Open();

            // create data adapter
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
        //    da.Fill(dataTable);
          //  conn.Close();
         //   da.Dispose();

             DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("desc");
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            table.Rows.Add(row);
            //Console.WriteLine("row added");                 
            da.Fill(table);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class Program { static void Main(string[] args) {
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sp2010/");
        Web web = context.Web;
        List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Emp");
        context.Load(list);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(list.Title + "\n");
        CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
        query.ViewXml = "<View/>";
        ListItemCollection allitems = list.GetItems(query);
        context.Load(allitems);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
        DataSet EmpDataSet = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        cn.ConnectionString = "";
        cn.Open();    
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from emp", cn);
        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da); // added
        da.Fill(EmpDataSet, "Emp");

        DataTable table = EmpDataSet.Tables[0];

        foreach (ListItem listitem in allitems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listitem["desc"].ToString()); 
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["desc"] = listitem["desc"].ToString();
            table.Rows.Add(row);
            builder.GetInsertCommand();// added
        }

        da.Update(EmpDataSet, "Emp");  

        conn.Close();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it is missing two statements  SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da); builder.GetInsertCommand();

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are disposing the dataadapter and SQl connection before filling it with datatable.

Comment: point taken .I have commented it , but still no luck

Comment: you should use the insert with paramaters as shown below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744746/sqlcommand-connection-string-for-localhost-database